# Is the copy constructor of `std::shared_ptr` atomic versus `reset()`?

Tags: c++, concurrency, shared-ptr

This is a verification question, to make sure I'm getting details right—language lawyers welcome.

I want to know that I can use `std::shared_ptr` in the following code and don't need to rewrite it with `atomic_shared_ptr`. The example has been simplified, but the essence is a possible race condition within a single instance of `example` between (*1) the copy constructor of `shared_ptr` and (*2) the call to `reset()`.

Note that a plain pointer for `p` won't work here. If `p` were to become null between the test and the call to `some_predicate`, you'd be indirecting a null pointer. That's the reason to use `shared_ptr` in the first place. I want to make sure I'm actually solving the race condition, not simply moving it elsewhere.

(It's not the point of the question, but this code might seem wrong at first glance. The behavior of `T` is idempotent. Once `p` has finished its job, it's not needed any more.)

```
template< class T >
class example
{
    shared_ptr< T > p ;
public:
    example()
        : p( make_shared( T() ) )
    {}
    void f()
    {
        shared_ptr< T > p_transient(p) ; // *1
        if ( p_transient && p_transient -> some_predicate() )
        {
            p.reset() ; // *2
        }
    }
};
```

Suppose that (*1) and (*2) execute simultaneously. I can think of two possible results of the race. (The code is correct in each of these two cases.) My question is whether these are the *only* cases:

- The copy takes effect before the `reset`, so `p_transient` keeps the member instance of `T` alive. The deleter runs in thread *1 when `f` returns. (The idempotence of `T` comes into play here.)
- `reset` takes effect before the copy, so `p_transient` is initialized empty. The deleter runs in thread *2 before `reset` returns.

I can't shake the feeling I'm getting something for nothing here, so I decided to write up the question. Anything I'm missing?

---

P.S. Here's what I was missing. `shared_ptr` isn't special. Somehow I thought it would be, perhaps because I've implemented smart pointers (too many) times before. Shared pointers, particularly when there are also weak pointers, pretty much require mutex protection for their (hidden) shared state. I figured that protection must have encompassed the entire object, but it doesn't.

Thanks to the responders for references to the standard. The general rule that data races result in undefined behavior is 1.10/27 "Multi-threaded executions and data races [intro.multithread]". In particular, it means that postconditions may be violated in such a situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is called a data race.  Any time one thread may write to some data and another thread may read or write that data, it is known as a data race.

Data races are **undefined behavior**.  This means there is no limit to what could occur.  I swear by the blog entry [Benign race cases: what could possibly go wrong?](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) for these sorts of things.  He goes through a list of things which *could* go wrong.

One example is that if you write to a memory location, the compiler is actually allowed to use this memory space to hold spilled registers.  It doesn't happen often, but it can happen.  The blog mentioned above shows an extreme example where a data race in this form launches a nuclear missile unintentionally!  (Here's hoping the real nuclear missile launch computers are a bit more robust!)

If you want to have two threads interacting with a piece of data, you must prevent data races.  This is usually done with mutexes or atomics.

Comment: I'm familiar with the general case. The question is very much about the specific guarantees that `std::shared_ptr` provides.

Comment: @eh9 ahh.  `std::shared_ptr` offers no guarantees, which is why I went to the general case. 2.7.2.2 clause 4 states how you should treat data races on shared_ptr ("member functions shall access and modify only the shared_ptr` ... objects themselves and not objects they refer to.") and `reset` is listed as a modifier of the object in 20.7.2.2.4.

Answer (score 2):

In order for #1 and #2 to execute simultaneously, then you must be calling `example::f` in two different threads. If these are on different `example` instances, then `example::p` would also be different instances, so there's no problem.

If these are on the *same* `example` instance, then you're violating C++ general rules about standard library race conditions. You're only (usually) guaranteed to be free from race conditions if you access different object *instances*. So you can `push_back` on two different `vector`s in two different threads, but not the *same* `vector`.

`shared_ptr` offers this same guarantee. So long as you're not trying to access the same `shared_ptr` instance from two different threads, it's fine. Once you do that, all bets are off.

The [atomic `shared_ptr` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) are for when you want to manipulate the same object atomically from different threads.

For example:

```
shared_ptr< T > p_transient(atomic_load(&p));
if ( p_transient && p_transient -> some_predicate() )
{
    atomic_store(&p, shared_ptr<T>());
}
```

Alternatively, you can just wrap `f` in a mutex or somesuch. That would also mean you wouldn't have to use a `shared_ptr`, since your possible destruction is also wrapped in the mutex.

Comment: Clarified the question to state that this is for a single instance, not multiple ones.

Comment: Where's the general rule about library races specified. I pulled out the standard to look up postconditions for `shared_ptr`, but I don't know where to find the exact wording.

Comment: @eh9: The general rule is stated by [res.on.data.races]. [util.smartpointer.shared]/4 explains the `shared_ptr`-specific behavior with regard to data races.